# Arduino UNO LED half brightness when connected to digital GND but not analog

Tags: arduino-uno, led, digital

I am using an Arduino UNO. When lighting an LED with the switch button on a joystick module, I have two situations:

- If the LED's cathode is connected to GND on the digital pin side of the Uno, the LED only dimly lights up on button press.
- If the LED's cathode is connected to GND on the analog pin side of the Uno, the LED fully lights up on button press.

The device is receiving power from my laptop, and I am writing a digital HIGH/LOW to the LED pin (on press/release).

Is this a fault in my board, or is there a (perhaps more enlightening) reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite double checking my cables before asking this question, it seems I had connected the LED's cathode to digital pin 13, and not GND. The issue is now resolved. Takeaway: Triple check your cables :)